# Facing issue Decimal to Binary in Python: Converting Error

Tags: python

I was trying to convert Decimal to Binary, there is no error in the code but while executing I am getting no result.

```
def decimalToBinary(ip_val):
    if ip_val= 1:
    # recursive function call
        decimalToBinary(ip_val // 2)
    
    # printing remainder from each function call
    print(ip_val % 2, end = '')
 
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # decimal value
    ip_val = 24
    
    # Calling special function
    decimalToBinary(ip_val)
```

Read Couple of blogs from Scaler, GeeksforGeeks, Tutorialstpoint etc. to understand the mistake i did, but as I am not able to figure it out the mistake.

Can someone help me to understand the mistake I did?

Thank you!

Comment: `if ip_val=1` is a syntax error! You meant `if ip_val >=1`.

Comment: So your statement `if ip_val =1` has a syntax error. It should be `==`. After that, it prints either `0` or `1` based on if there is a remainder. However, the print statement does that by itself and the recursive call to the function is kind of pointless with the way it's written.